# Convert 2D orthographic point to 3D vector on sphere?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems, projective-geometry, spherical-coordinates

Given a unit sphere (r=1) that is to be viewed orthographically from (x:1, y:0, z:0), how can I calculate the 3D vector point on surface for any given 2D coordinate?

Let's say I have a 100x100 pixels image of an orthographic unit sphere, viewed from (1,0,0), how can I find out which 3D coordinate is at pixel (x:40, y:40)?
I've tried using [this inverse formula on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_map_projection), but the results seems skewed:
(disregard red line and the off-center crosshair marker).

(we've attempted to loop through every pixel in an x*y 2D picture and deducing the vector, but the "equator" is completely stretched. Every point on the equator seem to be the same point somehow)

[image]

Comment: There are a few problems here: you haven't specified the camera rotation or field of view, and your camera point is touching the sphere (assuming the sphere is centered at the origin).

Comment: The camera touching the sphere is only a problem if you want perspective projection instead of orthographic projection. If you really mean orthographic projection, then when viewing from the x-direction, the screen coordinates are just the 3D $y,z$ coordinates (possibly scaled and rotated in 2D).

Comment: Is the answer not simply $x= \sqrt{ 1- y^2- z^2}$  where $(y,z)$ are the 2D coordinates of the point inside the unit circle?

Comment: @Karl I do mean orthographic, yes. What do you mean by $y,z$? Surely if I pick a 2D-coordinate, let's say (x:40, y:40), it wouldn't be correct to say that the 3D surface vector represented by that pixel is (x:0, y:40, z:40)? The actual point on the surface is not at x:0 (in cartesian?)

Comment: @MathWonk Is it really? I'll have to try that. I would assume it wouldn't be a unit vector after that, but maybe it would? I'll check it out when I've got time. If what you say is right then I have seriously misjudged what formula to use, and this would be a lot cheaper to perform..

Comment: @MathWonk You are right. I am dumb. Thank you.